# convert int to string in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to convert result of `select statement` to string:

```
SELECT count(*) from pg_largeobject
```

the result of this query will be an integer, i wanna convert it to string.

Ex: result is 12451 i want it as "12451" and its type is string .

i tried these solutions but not work:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-formatting.html

1- to_char()

```
to_char(SELECT count(*) from pg_largeobject, '')
```

but it require in second parameter the value that i dont know yet

2- cast(SELECT count(*) from pg_largeobject) as text;
it gives me :

> Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "cast"

Comment: `SELECT count(*)::varchar from pg_largeobject`, where '::varchar' is shorthand for `CAST` to `varchar`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver hi man, thanks , but it not working

Comment: I don't see why not? What is the command you are using and the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
select count(*)::TEXT from pg_catalog.pg_am;
 count 
-------
 7
```

Comment: hi man, it still consider the result as int , not string .

Comment: Must be the way you parse it. Output is left-aligned when using ::text.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast `count(*)` as text with `::text` syntax:

```
postgres=# create extension lo;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# SELECT count(*) from pg_largeobject;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(count(*)) from pg_largeobject;
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 bigint
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(count(*)::text) from pg_largeobject;
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 text
(1 row)

postgres=# select version();
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cast ( count(*)  as VARCHAR(10)) AS varchar_expression from pg_largeobject
```